# redirect users based on their browsers - htaccess or any other way

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I am designing a website and want to have different pages for different browsers since my page looks very bad in Firefox and IE

Can you please suggest me how to redirect users to different pages based on their browsers.

I would be grateful if you can provide me ready to use script since I am not a professional programmer but designing website for my personal use.

I would like my different pages for different browsers, such as

http:// mysite1 .com/IE.htm

http:// mysite1 .com/Chrome.htm

http:// mysite1 .com/Firefox.htm

http:// mysite1 .com/Safari.htm

Please provide the script for all browsers.
Thank you very very much.

Comment: Seems like exactly the sort of thing you should avoid doing ?

Comment: If you need different pages for each browser you're doing it all wrong.

Comment: Well You missed `Opera , Konqueror , ... and lot others` Why don't you design in a way that is compatible with every browsers ?

Comment: This used to be feasible back when IE and Netscape dominated the market, but it is a major waste of time now. As long as your website works it should not matter that the page looks a little different in the various browsers.

Comment: Probably, you should ask for detecting browsers in PHP (or whatever programming language is being used) so as to incorporate an appropriate stylesheet for that browser!

Answer (score 0):

**There are many, many web browsers, and many versions of browsers as some of the comments have highlighted, and it would be impossible to develop for all of them.**

With that said, since this is a personal project, and since you asked, here's a way to do it in PHP:

First, grab the useragent to pinpoint the browser using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. By comparing their useragent with those of common browsers, it **may** be possible to identify their browser. [A list of common useragents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) may come in useful.

Specifically, an example for Google Chrome (you may want to refine it to differentiate between chrome versions):

```
if(strpos($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome") !== False){
    header("Location: http://mysite1.com/Chrome.htm");
    //redirects the browser
}
```

Basically, we use `strpos()` to search the useragent for any occurrence of the string `Chrome`, which would strongly suggest a Chrome browser.

Do note that **useragents are notoriously unreliable** and that it is very easy to fake a useragent, so they should not be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the "my site looks bad in browser X" can be solved by CSS alone. There are multiple techniques that can help you with that, but i will explain two: one suggested by a [blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) by Paul Irish and the other one explained right here on in a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/169524/1669279).

**Browser sniffing**

HTML:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html>         <!--<![endif]-->
```

CSS:

```
div.foo { color: inherit;}
.ie6 div.foo { color: #ff8000; }
```

The basic idea is to use conditional comments to add a class to the root element indicating the IE version, allowing you to write specific rules for that version.

**CSS reset**

The default values for some properties in CSS are different between browsers. A CSS reset is a set of rules that makes these default values the same.

---

The advantage of using CSS to make your page look the same in different browsers is that the HTML is the same, making it much easier to maintain than having to update who knows how many pages whenever you need to add some text on the site.